# Some Sidekiq Jobs Not Getting Over and Consuming too much memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

One of my production servers has 3 processes of sidekiq processes running. The `top` command of these 3 sidekiq processes are shown below.

[image]

As you can see these 3 sidekiq processes are taking up almost 90% of the memory.

When I checked with the `netstat -antp | grep -e 94333` command. The output for the same is shown below:

```
tcp        0      0 some_ip_address:44896       redis_ip_address:6379       ESTABLISHED 94333/sidekiq 4.1.3
tcp        0      0 some_ip_address:56612       db_ip_address:5432        ESTABLISHED 94333/sidekiq 4.1.3
tcp        0      0 some_ip_address:44900       redis_ip_address:6379       ESTABLISHED 94333/sidekiq 4.1.3
tcp        0      0 some_ip_address:44934       redis_ip_address:6379       ESTABLISHED 94333/sidekiq 4.1.3
tcp        0      0 some_ip_address:44902       redis_ip_address:6379       ESTABLISHED 94333/sidekiq 4.1.3
tcp        0      0 some_ip_address:60158       elasticsearch_ip_address:9200        ESTABLISHED 94333/sidekiq 4.1.3
tcp        0      0 some_ip_address:57798       db_ip_address:5432        ESTABLISHED 94333/sidekiq 4.1.3
tcp        0      0 some_ip_address:44894       redis_ip_address:6379       ESTABLISHED 94333/sidekiq 4.1.3
tcp        0      0 some_ip_address:56754       db_ip_address:5432        ESTABLISHED 94333/sidekiq 4.1.3
tcp        0      0 some_ip_address:56620       db_ip_address:5432        ESTABLISHED 94333/sidekiq 4.1.3
tcp        0      0 some_ip_address:44916       redis_ip_address:6379       ESTABLISHED 94333/sidekiq 4.1.3
tcp        0      0 some_ip_address:44904       redis_ip_address:6379       ESTABLISHED 94333/sidekiq 4.1.3
tcp        0      0 some_ip_address:44888       redis_ip_address:6379       ESTABLISHED 94333/sidekiq 4.1.3
.
.
.
```

Above are only some of the lines of the output. The real output is much bigger than shown above. And similar is the case with the other processes of sidekiq.

Why is the `netstat` command showing so many established connections with Sidekiq, Database and Elasticsearch? Is that expected? Are these established connections the reason for high memory usage? How can I reduce the memory consumption of these sidekiq processes?

Comment: How many threads do you have per sidekiq process?

Comment: I have 25 threads per sidekiq process. But none of them are busy right now. All the above commands were run when none of the threads are busy.